# Should there be a canonical resource for OAuth 2.0 on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, needs-more-focus

I think a question like *[The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)* should be allowed as it gives much information in an indexed manner to a beginner.

I therefore wrote a similar question: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893660/the-definitive-guide-to-oauth2-0-authentication*

I think this format would help a lot on collecting information on OAuth 2.0 from available experts, as opposed to a single blogger maintaining the page.

Comment: Why do you think such questions should be allowed, and how do you propose to keep them falling into the 'way too many answers' trap?

Comment: as you can see the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication . give much information about form based authentication so one dont have to write multiple query if all things are indexed in a single documentation @PetterFriberg

Comment: I've often found "The definitive guide to form-based website authentication" useful. I believe a similar post for OAuth 2.0 would be useful. Moderation of it would be an issue, but let's not dismiss this idea out of hand.

Comment: Such Question is a good Guide Because it contain point to point answer by experienced people and moderator can always moderate it . it would save a lot of other unrelated question being asked . it can be one place for all answer. i think it can be a good idea @MartijnPieters

Comment: @DrStrange001: please edit your question to add your motivations. 'I think it can be a good idea' is too subjective; we already know you think it is a good idea, because you posted this meta question. You need to convince everyone else that it is a good idea, so bring *objective reasons*. Moderators won't just moderate such posts, we disallow too broad questions because moderating such posts is not a good use of our time. Take into account your post won't be the only such posts if we were to allow them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Post like This With Technology That wont change rapidly like oAuth 2.0 is much benificial for beginners and all people as all the information can be found there and i know this can become spam so user can downvote them which they usally do and mode can delete all downvoted answer that a suggestion i think

Comment: @S.L.Barth a canonical is ok, it just needs to be scoped correctly and answers should not contain a list of links. Hence not a request for documentation, nor over excessively broad.

Comment: @DrStrange001: but **other sites** can offer the same information. You could post it on your own blog, for example, and then answers here could reference that information. Stack Overflow doesn't need to provide **everything**. Posting it on your own blog would have the huge advantage that *other people won't be posting more huge answers*.

Comment: @DrStrange001 is that a way of saying 'I would like this to be available, but I want someone else to put in the time, effort and expense of doing it'?

Comment: @MartinJames i dont mean that if i am writing this documentation post than for sure i would have done some research but i would not be able to understand all aspects . so people who have already implemented can help me on how to start thats why i told that

Comment: @MartinJames what about "I have this question and I wish someone to look at it and put in the time, effort and expense to solve it?" I mean, if we could provide a programming resource to programmers at large it can't be bad per se. However this reminds me a lot the failed "Documentation" saga.

Comment: for oAuth i have read many blogs and reading blogs by a single author confuses as many author have different views and they express differently so having a single knowledge repo would be much benificial for this as it will provide new programmers a central repo

Comment: @Steve The Documentation project failed for a variety of reasons. I think we can avoid these in a canonical Q&A.

Comment: I think i was wrong to append the word documentation but a definative indexed information much me like a good resource and it people would not ask some common repetetive question that can be ease for moderator.

Comment: This meta question have changed, I have removed my comments as they were related to creating a *Definitive Guide* and not a canonical

Comment: Why do you insist on misspelling the main topic, OAuth, both here and in that Stack Overflow question?

Comment: Why downvoting the thread atleast explain your views ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've often found "The definitive guide to form-based website authentication" useful.

And having struggled to understand OAuth 2.0 in the past, I believe a similar post for OAuth 2.0 would be useful too.

So in principle, I would like to have this as a canonical Q&A.

- **Many websites use OAuth 2.0**.
  By having a canonical resource, we can help new(ish) developers get their OAuth 2.0 implementations right. This makes the web a safer place for all.
- **A canonical on SO is moderated by several experts, rather than a single blogger**
  There are several blogs about OAuth 2.0, some better than others. But they're written by individuals, and scattered all over the web. By having a post on SO, we can have several experts work together to create a good resource. We don't have to rely on a single blogger to update their post in response to comments.
- **A canonical is easier to find than a tag wiki**
  We can put a lot of info in a tag wiki, but tag wikis are less easy to find using search engines. Also, tag wikis are intended to give some basic information, not to be definitive guides. A canonical Q&A can have several answers, giving us more space to cover everything that is needed.
- **We need something more legible than the RFC**
  Even as I write, a hardcopy of RFC 6749 is lying on my desk. I've referred to it over and over. But it is not a document that is easy to read; nor is it required to. It is an official spec and (hence) an authorative resource. Anyone dealing with OAuth 2.0 intensively will need it at some point. But if we can provide people with a resource that is easier to read, it will also help them use the RFC more effectively. They will then understand the protocol better, helping them to understand the RFC. And helping them to more effectively find what they need, when the time comes that they need to refer to the RFC.

My main concern is moderation. As Petter Friberg points out in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366187/documentation-type-question-should-be-allowed-on-stack-overflow#comment575512_366187), such canonical "Definitive Guide To ..."  posts can easily become spam magnets. We might want to make them Community Wiki, or give them protected status, to prevent the worst.

But since OAuth 2.0 is a strictly defined protocol, I for one believe we can get this canonical Q&A right. It won't always be easy, but I believe it will be worth the effort.

Comment: This covers *one specific example*. The OP seems to be asking for this kind of question to be allowed *in general*.

Comment: Not in general for topics which dont change much rapidly like Oauth and C++ like that

Comment: Try to edit the question, find a better scope, remove "*Definitive Guide"*, consider this https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=OAuth%202.0&mixed=0, specify framework if need etc and yes canonical's are appreciated but they need to follow standard Q/A format to be maintainable. As far as title *"Documentation type question should be allowed on Stack Overflow?"*, I think you need to address this, again the scope of this meta question seems to be different.

Comment: I'd like to add that in that case the question should be made CW ASAP, to avoid one person getting 4000+ upvotes for a community effort, and that only a single CW answer is added, and then the question re-closed to prevent a multitude of answers; just use an index on top of the CW answer if it gets very big.

Comment: maybe the question here is: *Do we need a canonical for OAuth 2.0 in .net?*

Comment: @PetterFriberg I don't think a canonical OAuth 2.0 guide should be framework-specific. We might have answers that address specific frameworks, especially if a popular framework has known pitfalls.

Comment: I'm not well versed in OAuth 2.0 but consider this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727226/on-a-high-level-how-does-oauth-2-work if you create a canonical

Comment: We dont want Specific framework implementation as common question can be answered one can code itself .

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks, I'll have a look. I've als noted that I misspelled your name at first (from the first edit), from now on I'll spell it right ;-)

Comment: @DrStrange001 Give it a little time. You've only asked the question an hour ago. Many users haven't even seen it yet. More people may have ideas, suggestions and criticisms.

Comment: Ohk  . Lets Wait And see what would be the result